# Install a Canon Canoscan Lide 110

Tags: canon, scanner

How do I install a Canon Canoscan Lide 110? I gather from previous postings that it's possible but it's not clear to me what to do. I need step by step instructions please. Thanks.

Comment: If the drivers aren't includedin Ubuntu by standard and Canon doesn't provide them then your only choice is to write them yourself.

Comment: If people still have this problem, they may find [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersCanon) useful.

Answer (score 7):

Described problems are two years old. Probably you don't have to do anything to make it work, as other posters confirm, that it is included in Ubuntu. If you are new to Ubuntu you have to know, that most scanners and printers are installed by default. That means you just have to connect the USB-Cable to your computer, open "Simple Scan" (Open the Dash pressing Super or Windows next to Alt, then write "simple scan" enter) and press Scan.

If no scanner is found, you will get a message.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for Canon CanoScan LiDE 110 under KUbuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for Canon CanoScan LiDE 110 under KUbuntu 22.04 LTS. and the app name has become >>Document Scanner<< now.

Answer (score 2):

For my LIDE 110  scanner I found the following solution

Just install *Simple Scan* or *Skanlite* from the Ubuntu Software Center. They are multiple scanners, but you can both text and jpg fetch with it. I used previously Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.

Comment: @A.B. I don't know if this answer will help or not, but it *does* present information not covered by any other answer to this question. In particular, it suggests using Skanlite, which isn't mentioned elsewhere in any of the posts here. (As for the age of the question, I'm not sure how that's relevant--I hope you're not suggesting old open questions shouldn't be answered.) **Walter Debeuf**: What do you mean by "multiple scanners," and can you explain what "text and jpg fetch" are? If you choose to add more information to your answer, you can do so by [edit]ing it.

Comment: @EliahKagan OK I understand.